# Syncing two databases

Tags: yii2

For example, I have 2 web sites and 2 different hosting accounts and if I have a new record in the first database it should be also inserted in 2 database.

Problem is that, it can be absolutely different hosting accounts and it can be problems with access, the main purpose is to see statisctis of sales. Or may be there are other alternatives how to do it? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by creating master-slave MySQL instance, 
any change in master will automatically reflect in slave - you don't have to do this manually.

follow docs:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/set-up-mysql-master-slave-replication/

https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc9/worked-examples/worked-example-comparing-and-synchronizing-two-databases

and many more, google it.